# Translate a url into a set of GET parameters

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

I would like to translate a url with parameters to a path, i.e.

```
http://www.example.com/?page=1 => http://www.example.com/1
http://www.example.com/?section=books&category=thriller&page=1 => http://www.example.com/books/thriller/1
```

And then i would like to be able to get all this parameters to use them in a query in order to make a select based on this parameters, i don't know where to start, how can i do it? I'm using this .htaccess to redirect all my requests to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can i "translate" a path to a set of parameters to use them in a query?

Comment: What is the question? Your redirect doesn't work? Your php script doesn't handle the request correctly?

Comment: It's written: "I would like to be able to extract parameters from a path, to be able to make a query to the db with them"

Comment: your question is not clear ,you ask something then its contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it backwards. You want to have the request come in from the user as `http://www.example.com/books/thriller/1`, then rewrite *that* to `index.php?qs=$1` for PHP to handle. This way the user sees the 'friendly' URLs, and PHP sees the format that is friendly to it.

So your rewrite rule would change to something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?qs=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And then you can access its contents via:

```
$myQueryVars = explode('/', $_GET['qs']);
```

`http://www.example.com/books/thriller/1` becomes

```
array( 'books', 'thriller', '1' )
```

Comment: this seems to be working, but what can i do if an user adds some parameter? i.e. `http://www.example.com/books/thriller/1?a=234`

Comment: @Harlandraka then you will have `$_GET['qs']` as well as `$_GET['a']`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like this ...

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?section=$1&category=$2&page=$3
```